# Resizing High Quality images for web

Tags: c#, image

Hi Guys I am resizing Images in C# and saving them as .png.

```
public static Bitmap resize(int x, int y, Image p)
{
    Bitmap Img = new Bitmap(x,y);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(Img))
    {
        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        gr.DrawImage(p, new Rectangle(0, 0, x, y));
    }
    return Img;
}
```

The problem is that when a user uploads a high quality image such as Images from high end smartphones such as galaxys, iphones etc the filesize of the resulting resized image is quite high.
I have constructed a table of resized images file size and pixel size.

```
1) Img1  1280 * 666px => 458 kb
2) Img1  300 * 399px => 221kb
3) Img2  1280 * 1444px => 2.08mb
4) Img2  300 * 451px => 327kb
```

I know I have interpolation and smoothing set to high quality for example purposes and saving images as .png to preserve transparency. But what setting should I change to obtain a Image of reasonable quality and filesize ideal for HTML pages. My end goal is making a compromise between Image quality and FileSize. So please point me to to some link demonstrating Filsesize vs Quality comparison for quality of resized images so that I can make the choice myself.

Comment: Do you really have to save photos as .png? Why?

Comment: @hyde It can be photos or vectors so I need to preserve transparency.

Comment: Do you always have transparency, even with photos?

Comment: @hyde not always maybe 3 times out of 10.

Comment: Perhaps you could save the target image in the same format as the source, so that if you have a hi-res jpg image it is also saved as a jpg image rather than always using png.

Comment: Well then, only use png when you have to, jpg otherwise... Also, asking for offsite resources is offtopic at SO, question and answers should be mostly self-contained. Clarify the question a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one option you can play with, the `PixelFormat`.

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x, y, 
         System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
{
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {

        gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        gr.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, x, y));
    }
}
```

Use 32 bit Argb only if you need the alpha channel (e.g. the image is transparent). You can also query the `img.PixelFormat` to see if the image even contains an alpha channel!
In this case you don't have to save it as PNG and can go with JPG which will result in lot smaller files!

Normal jpg usually use `Format24bppRgb`.

Answer (score 1):

Use JPEG instead and [adjust the compression](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/graph/controlling-jpeg-compression) for the quality you need.